# Mapping from String to Tuple2<String, Long> in Spark + Java

Tags: java, apache-spark

I'm trying to learn how to use Spark, coding in Java (please no Scala code). I'm trying to implement the very simple *hello world* example of Spark, a word count.

I've borrowed the code from Spark's documentation [quick start](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html):

```
/* SimpleApp.java */
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;

public class SimpleApp {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String logFile = "YOUR_SPARK_HOME/README.md"; // Should be some file on your system
    SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Simple Application").getOrCreate();
    Dataset<String> logData = spark.read().textFile(logFile).cache();

    long numAs = logData.filter(s -> s.contains("a")).count();
    long numBs = logData.filter(s -> s.contains("b")).count();

    System.out.println("Lines with a: " + numAs + ", lines with b: " + numBs);

    spark.stop();
  }
}
```

All is good, now I want to replace the `filter` with a `flatMap` and then a `map`. I've got the `flatMap` so far:

```
    logData.flatMap((FlatMapFunction<String, String>) l -> {
                          return Arrays.asList(l.split(" ")).iterator();
                    }, Encoders.STRING());
```

Now, I want to map each word to a Tuple2 `(word, 1)` and then group them by key. But the problem is that I cannot find how to get from `String` to `(String, Long)`. Most documentations talk about `mapToPair` but `Dataset` does not have such a method!

Can someone help me map a `String` to `Tuple2<String, Long>`? BTW, I'm not even sure if I'm looking for `Tuple2` or some other class.

**[UPDATE]**

Based on the suggestion provided by @mangusta, I tried this:

```
    logData.flatMap((FlatMapFunction<String, String>) l -> {
        return Arrays.asList(l.split(" ")).iterator();
    }, Encoders.STRING())
    .map(new Function<String, Tuple2<String, Long>>() {
        public Tuple2<String, Long> call(String str) {
            return new Tuple2<String, Long>(str, 1L);
        }
    })
    .count()
```

And faced this compile error:

```
Error:(108, 17) java: no suitable method found for map(<anonymous org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function<java.lang.String,scala.Tuple2<java.lang.String,java.lang.Long>>>)
    method org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<U>map(scala.Function1<java.lang.String,U>,org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder<U>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) U
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
    method org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<U>map(org.apache.spark.api.java.function.MapFunction<java.lang.String,U>,org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder<U>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) U
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
```

Seems like the `map` function takes in two parameters. I'm not sure what should I pass as the second parameter.

Comment: In your quick start link, try looking at the `groupByKey(identity).count` example

Comment: Thanks but that's only Scala and Python code. I don't see any Java example for `groupByKey`!

Comment: That doesn't mean the method doesn't exist ;)

Comment: The documentation for `groupByKey` says `When called on a dataset of (K, V) pairs` but my items are still singles (not pairs). Don't you think I should first convert them to pairs before I can call `groupbyKey`?

Comment: By the way, if you're using Java 8, why are you typing out each anonymous class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure the reason for the error, but you can try this code

```
final String sparkHome = "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.3.2";
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf()
        .setMaster("local[*]")
        .setAppName("spark-example")
        .setSparkHome(sparkHome + "/libexec");

SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().config(conf).getOrCreate();
Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().textFile(sparkHome + "/README.md")
        .flatMap(line -> Arrays.asList(line.split(" ")).iterator(), Encoders.STRING())
        .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
        .map(word -> new Tuple2<>(word.toLowerCase(), 1L), Encoders.tuple(Encoders.STRING(), Encoders.LONG()))
        .toDF("word", "count")
        .groupBy("word")
        .sum("count").orderBy(new Column("sum(count)").desc()).withColumnRenamed("sum(count)", "_cnt");

df.show(false);
```

And you should expect this output

```
+-------------+----+
|word         |_cnt|
+-------------+----+
|the          |25  |
|to           |19  |
|spark        |16  |
|for          |15  |
|and          |10  |
|a            |9   |
|##           |9   |
|you          |8   |
|run          |7   |
|on           |7   |
|can          |7   |
|is           |6   |
|in           |6   |
|of           |5   |
|using        |5   |
|including    |4   |
|if           |4   |
|with         |4   |
|documentation|4   |
|an           |4   |
+-------------+----+
only showing top 20 rows
```

Comment: the error occured because he didn't put in `Encoders.tuple(Encoders.STRING(), Encoders.LONG())` specified in your map's 2nd argument

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use `Tuple2`, you should use Scala library for Java, i.e. `scala-library.jar`

To prepare tuples from some `JavaRDD<String> data`, you may apply the following function to that RDD:

```
JavaRDD<Tuple2<String,Long>> tupleRDD  =  data.map(

new Function<String, Tuple2<String, Long>>() {

            public Tuple2<String, Long> call(String str) {

              return new Tuple2<String, Long>(str, 1L);

            }//end call

          }//end function

        );//end map
```

Comment: Thanks, but how does that help?

Comment: well, you asked "Now, I want to map each word to a Tuple2", so if you want to do that, you need to initialize a `Tuple2` as `new Tuple2<String, Long>(your_word, 1L)`

Comment: But which (and how) method should I use to map from word to `Tuple2`? The question is not a matter of how to instantiate the `Tuple2` object. But how to go from `String` to `Tuple2<String, Long>` and not for a single item, but for the whole dataset.

Comment: see the updated answer. I didn't use lambda expression but it's straightforward to change it to lambda if necessary

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and faced a compile error. Please find it in my updated question.

Comment: my map should be applied on string RDD. seems that your "logData.flatMap( )" returns RDD for list of strings, not string RDD

Comment: No. `logData` and the return value of `flatMap` both are of type `Dataset<String>, and not `RDD`. And I believe the code you've provided is correct but not complete. Even the `flatMap` (as you can see in the given code) accepts two parameters. While for the `flatMap` I could guess what I needed for it, in this case, I have no clue!

Comment: right, you're using `Dataset` instead of `RDD`. i never used `Dataset` so far but I suspect that the first argument of dataset's map method may be identical to the one in my answer, while the second argument `org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder<U>` could be `Encoders.STRING()`. After getting tuples, you call `reduceByKey( )` or `groupByKey( )` or whichever method there is for reduction, and specify lambda as somthing like `(a,b) -> a + b`

Comment: calling `count( )` after map doesn't make sense as your purpose is to count per key, not count everything

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 logData.flatMap((FlatMapFunction<String,String>)line -> Arrays.asList(line.split(" ")).iterator(), Encoders.STRING()).groupBy("value").count().show();
```